# Format data for high charts representation

Tags: node.js, typescript, highcharts

I have data in the below format. I want to plot a line chart to compare data for years 2017 and 2018 for al the months with total.

```
const listItems = [{
    "id": 1,
    "total": 21.15,
    "dat": "2017-10-21T08:32:36.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "total": 22,
    "dat": "2017-11-24T13:46:16.000Z"
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "total": 11,
    "dat": "2017-11-24T13:46:16.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "total": 12,
    "dat": "2018-04-02T09:15:35.000Z",
  }
]
```

i want to represent Line chart in the below format :

```
var xAxis = {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
    ]
};
var series = [{
        name: '2017',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,
            26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6
        ]
    },
    {
        name: '2018',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8,
            24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5
        ]
    }
];
```

basically the data represents sum of all the months .

Comment: Cool. But do you have a question?

Comment: Could you describe how this chart should look like? As I understood, you have got a basic chart like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L1rmbaw6/, but I don't get how this total should look like. It should be another series on the same chart? The image could be really useful...

Answer (score 0):

First, write a function that mines month from date, for example:

```
var dateToMonth = (date) => {
    var matched = /[\d]{4}-([\d]{2})-[.]*/g.exec(date)[1];
    return matched;
};
```

also write someone else for mining year. And even an in_array function:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you have to write a function that iterates your data and sum sum data of same months:

```
var format = (data) => {
    var month_format = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    var last_format = [];
    data.map(e => {
        var year = dateToYear(e.date);
        var years = last_format.map(data_e => data_e.name);
        if (!inArray(year, years)) last_format.add({name: year, data: month_format});
        var month = dateToMonth(e.date);
        last_format.forEach(i => {
           if (i.name === year) i[month - a] += e.data;
        });
    });
    return last_format;
};
```